# Confusion with modelling logistic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To a first approximation the logistic equation is modelled as

$\frac{dP}{dt} = \mu P$ (eq.1)

I don't quite understand where this assumption comes from mathematically. In my mind I can consider

$\frac{dP}{dt} = F(P)$

which is an approximation in itself, albeit less strenuous than (eq.1). We can then consider a Taylor expansion about an arbitrary point, say the initial population $P_{0}$, thus

$\frac{dP}{dt} = F(P) = F(P_{0})+F'(P_{0})(P-P_{0})+O(|P-P_{0}|^{2} )$

Solving the above differential equation (keeping only two terms) with the initial condition $t=0;P=P_{0}$ yields,

$P(t)=\frac{F(P_{0})}{F'(P_{0})}e^{F'(P_{0})t}+P_{0}-\frac{F(P_{0})}{F'(P_{0})}$

Now, I can perform experiments (short time intervals) to find $F(P_{0})$ and $F'(P_{0})$ and use these values to 'predict' how my model evolves.

Is my reasoning misguided? Could someone explain what are the assumptions for (eq.1) and why the first Taylor term (constant) has disappeared in the literature's approximation?

Comment: The first equation is the law of natural growth. If $P(t)$ is the value of a quantity at time $t$ and if the rate of change of $P$ with respect to $t$ is proportional to its size $P(t)$ at any time, then

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=\mu P$$

where $\mu$ is a constant. Many quantities grow or decay at a rate proportional to their size.

Comment: An example is bacteria growth. Suppose a colony of bacteria doubles every hour. If the size of the colony after $t$ hours is given by $P(t)$, then we can express this information in mathematical language in the form of an equation:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}= 2P$$

when we solve this equation we would find exponential growth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logistic equation is $dP/dT = \mu P (1-P/R)$, where $R$ is the carrying capacity of the environment.

The function on the right-hand side, $F(P) = \mu P (1-P/R) = \mu P - (\mu/R) P^2$, is a polynomial, hence it is its own Maclaurin expansion, with $F(0)=0$ and $F'(0)=\mu$.

So the constant term $F(0)$ is already zero to begin with. And dropping the higher-order term $-(\mu/R) P^2$, you get the simpler equation $dP/dT = \mu P$, whose solution $P(t)=P(0) e^{\mu t}$ is an approximation to the solution of the logistic equation if you start with an initial value $P(0)$ close to zero. The approximation is good to begin with, but gets worse as $e^{\mu t}$ grows larger (which it does pretty quickly).

Comment: Ok, so we are expanding about $P=0$. But then surely it is better to expand about $P=P_{0}$ to get a better approximation close to the starting value? Also what is the physical intuition for imposing $F(0)=0$? Does it mean 'if there is no population there is no rate of change of that population?'

Comment: Moreover, if the logistic equation is used to model bacteria say, then the Maclaurin expansion will be absolutely horrible given that the initial value of the population is extremely high and thus 'far away' from its point of expansion...

Comment: The point isn't *really* to get a good approximation to the solution, since you can solve the logistic equation exactly anyway. It's rather to compare the eqation to another (simpler) equation that's presumably known already. But yes, $F(0)=0$ means that “no population” is an equilibrium state. Regarding the inital value of a bacterial population being extremely high, that's a rather meaningless statement. You can't use absolute numbers for such a comparison, the relevant condition is that the dimensionless quantity $P(0)/R$ should much less than $1$.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense to me now. The Maclaurin expansion is justified because we non-dimensionalise 'appropriately'. Finally, we assume that a null-population is an equilibrium state. I can live with those assumptions, thank you.